# Get value of plsql procedure from java

Tags: java, hibernate, plsql, persistence

I want to get parameters from PLSQL Proceduer.

```
PROCEDURE BALANCE(requestDate in date, uniqueId in number, field1 out varchar2, field2 out varchar2)
AS 
BEGIN
    field1 := '110';
    field2 := '100';
END BALANCE;
```

And this is java code:

```
 javax.persistence.Query query = pm.getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(" declare a number(10);" +
            " b number(10);" +
            " begin BALANCE(:date,:id,a,b); end;");
    query.setParameter("date", transaction.getTransactionId().getRequestDate());
    query.setParameter("id", transaction.getTransactionId().getId());
    query.executeUpdate();
```

I want to use 'a' and 'b' in java program and I don't know how to get 'a' and 'b'?
Thanks.

Comment: First of all what are `a` and `be` here? Next is you can use callable statements to call a procedure and access results.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't need hibernate but JDBC. You don't have aany Entity for the out params.

TO call them just register the ut parameters and get them back after calling statement.

```
String getDBUSERByUserIdSql = "{call getDBUSERByUserId(?,?,?,?)}";
callableStatement = dbConnection.prepareCall(getDBUSERByUserIdSql);
callableStatement.setInt(1, 10);
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(3, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(4, java.sql.Types.DATE);

// execute getDBUSERByUserId store procedure
callableStatement.executeUpdate();

String userName = callableStatement.getString(2);
String createdBy = callableStatement.getString(3);
Date createdDate = callableStatement.getDate(4);
```

The code from [the example](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-callablestatement-stored-procedure-out-parameter-example/)